# Loading xlsx files into dataframes using openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

So I have made this code, it goes smoothly through all the files but doesn't write them into the database.
Someone maybe know the fix for this?

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import openpyxl



files= [file for file in os.listdir(r'path')]

a = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    wb= openpyxl.load_workbook(r'path'+file)
    print (wb)
    for ws in wb.sheetnames:
        ws = wb[ws]
        data = ws.values
        columns= next(data)[0:]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
     d= pd.concat([df,a])

print (a)
```

Comment: What do you mean write them into the database? Are you basically trying to create one massive DF from all sheets in all workbooks in the path?

Comment: Yes, that is what I've meant.

Comment: You only concat the last sheet of each file to a new unused df.... Change the last line to `a = pd.concat([df,a])` and put it inside the **inner** loop

Comment: @Tomerikoo except this one step further of *all* sheets from *multiple* files

Comment: @JonClements well it's a pretty small step that OP should be able to handle

Comment: That helped, thanks a lot.